# Error while executing command: node --max_old_space_size=3072 node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js build

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, vue.js, vuejs2, aws-codebuild

I some projects in AWS codeBuild, the problem i have is that since yesterday i have been getting this error in the build

```
[Container] 2020/03/09 12:51:00 Running command node --max_old_space_size=3072 node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js build --mode production

-  Building for production...
Killed

[Container] 2020/03/09 12:53:29 Command did not exit successfully node --max_old_space_size=3072 node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js build --mode production exit status 137
[Container] 2020/03/09 12:53:29 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2020/03/09 12:53:29 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: node --max_old_space_size=3072 node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js build --mode production. Reason: exit status 137
```

I know the probably the project is trying to use more than 3072Mb of ram, but i don't know why, i have another project that have more pages and components and it have not throw that error.

So here the questions

How can i know how much ram is using the node to build the vue project in local?
How can i optimize the build process?
The node modules has to do with this? this project with the error has more packages than the other one.

Answer (score 0):

A few webpages such as following suggest that it is probably a RAM issue.

- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4008

The node command in the error message has the —- max-old-space-size flag which sets the memory limit to 3gb rather than the default of 512 mb.

- https://medium.com/@vuongtran/how-to-solve-process-out-of-memory-in-node-js-5f0de8f8464c

This 3gb value should match the compute type the build project:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-compute-types.html

You maybe using 'build.general1.small' which has 3gb but node may not be able to allocate all of it.

So can you try the command with a lesser amount of memory reading, e.g.

```
$ node --max_old_space_size=2560 node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js build --mode production
```

Or you can try to upgrade the compute type but that may incur a price increase.